# Simpson user define function in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math, symbolic-math

How I can get user define function in c# .Function get from text-box in form of string and pass to this function in double

```
Simpson(Func<double, double> f, double a, double b, int pointsNum)
```

e.g `Func<double, double> f = x => Math.Cos(x);`

i hard code this.
but how can i get it from text-box?

Comment: Not easily. You are asking to have something that is purely syntax sugar (and replaced at compile time) be dynamic. There are ways to get the result dynamically, but I don't believe you can get back as a delegate (`Func` is a delegate) in order to pass it in.

Comment: If you're not particular about what language you use for the user-inputted function, the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) could be useful.  It has facilities for dynamically running, e.g. Python code that is loaded at runtime.

Comment: With a dictionary, with a parser or compiling code at runtime. Depends how many functions you have to support, if you need to support expressions, performance and and and

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the function this can be a simple or a complex task. If you allow the user just to use a few simple operators (+, -, /, %), and basic math functions (a defined number of functions), then you can create a parser, parse the function code, and execute it then. But this will be very limited, like a simple calculator.

If you want to allow the user to do complex things, then you need to programatically compile code with C#. There is a `CSharpCodeProvider` class - have a look at it please.

There is `System.CodeDom` namespace that is well documented, it defines types that can represent the logical structure of source code, independent of a specific programming language. search for it in MSDN and Google. You should Google for `C# dynamic code compile`.